# Persisting data involving special characters using JPA and MySQL

Tags: java, jpa

I'm trying to persist some data using JPA repositories into my MySQL database.
I could successfully insert data into the table and the special characters are saved correctly as my tables are utf8 enabled. But, when I'm trying to modify the data and persist using JPA repository's save method the 'μ' gets converted to '?'.

My database connection already has been set to `useUnicode=yes&amp;characterEncoding=UTF-8`, still when I save data using the API it doesn't save special characters. Can someone tell me where I'm going wrong?

Comment: How does your persistence.xml look?

Comment: What is the ASCII/Integer value of the character?

Comment: Check the encoding of your source code files, are they also UTF8?

Comment: @JorgeCampos It is UTF-8 enabled.